# Why is the style of TabLayout giving error?

Tags: android, android-styles

I have made a change in my style xml file to have some custom style defined for my TabLayout.

My code :

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
<item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Also I would like to ask that when I did my research it showed that I should use
`<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">` in there so from where did the `parent` came. I went through the documentation but this `TextAppearance.Design.Tab` was no where to be found. So why does the app does not work without this parent and from where can I get to know the exact aim of the parent.

Comment: Are you just trying to change the text in your tabs?

Comment: check: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: @Eenvincible But the question is more broader. In the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:tabTextAppearance there is nothing as parent or anything is shown. So from where did that parent text came ?

Comment: @piotrek1543 I have been through that. That just gave me the list but didn't give me the source or reason from where the parent property came.

Comment: I just want to know what you really want to achieve with this;  I have code that you can use to programmatically change font, text size etc for tabs

Comment: @Eenvincible I want to change the text size and the background color of TabLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sample code:

```
public static void changeTabsAttributes(TabLayout tabLayout, int textSize) {

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                //set the background somewhere here?
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextSize(textSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try this then tell me what you get! Can't you also change background color using xml for the tablayout?

Comment: I just want to have one text size and a background using style. I don't want  different properties for each tab,

Comment: Then you can simply have this one method then call it when you need custom text size and background color in tablayout. If you don't want to try this, try the xml some more